# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Tags: php, api, curl, file-get-contents

I am calling rest api using file_get_contents with basic authentication. This request is working fine in Postman, but it is responding 404 with file_get_contents.

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => json_encode($data),
        'header'  => "Content-Type: application/json\r\nAuthorization: Basic " . base64_encode('username:password') . "\r\n",
    ),
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: How you are calling the code other than using Postman?

Comment: With Xampp server and browser @RopAliMunshi

Comment: Is the URL and username/password correct?

Comment: @uppervali team by entering the url in the browser?

Comment: Username and password is correct @SalmanA

Comment: Using local IP in browser @RopAliMunshi

Comment: @uppervali team you can't directly make the POST request in the browser.

Comment: I am not making directly POST request. Making this request using file_get_contents() function. @RopAliMunshi

Comment: @uppervaliteam did you find any solution for this?